# Issue reinstalling yarn - code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, yarnpkg

- **Node.js Version**:14.0.0
- **OS**: MacOS 10.15.4
- **Scope (install, code, runtime, meta, other?)**: Yarn install
- **Module (and version) (if relevant)**: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js

Upon running any Yarn command, I get the following error. This is after reinstalling and following this sequence of commands:

---

YARN UNINSTALL:

yarn cache clean

1. open terminal
2. rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock yarn-error.log package-lock.json
3. brew uninstall --force yarn
4. npm uninstall -g yarn
5. yarn -v
6. which yarn
7. rm -rf ~/.yarn (OPTIONAL, not recommended)
8. rm -rf /usr/local/bin/yarn
9. rm -rf /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg
10. which yarn

NPM & NODE UNINSTALL:

1. keep adding to terminal
2. brew uninstall --force node
3. brew cleanup
4. sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}
5. sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp
6. sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
7. sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
8. brew doctor
9. brew cleanup --prune-prefix

INSTALL:

1. same terminal
2. brew install yarn
3. brew install node
4. brew link node
5. sudo chmod 776 /usr/local/lib
6. brew link --overwrite node
7. sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/lib
8. brew link node
9. yarn policies set-version
10. n 12.13.1

    ### 11. yarn -v && node -v && npm -v

Then the following appears on terminal upon running yarn command at step 9 of the install:

```
USER-MacBook-Pro:~ User$ yarn
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1017
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/jlagos/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.21.1.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1014:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ ]
}
```

Any help on how to restore Yarn? Seems like node is keeping track of a previous yarn version.

Answer (score 2):

I keep running into the same issue whenever I update yarn as well.
Something possibly in the (currently unseen) $PATH that I've yet to be able to remove.

As @jlagos pointed out, you can trick the system to run the latest version instead of 1.21.1 by copying over the latest over that location.

If you have yet to install or see yarn at `/.yarn/` you can install it directly following https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/ or

`curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash`

Then create and copy of the file location with the following:

```sh
mkdir ~/.yarn/releases/
cp ~/.yarn/lib/cli.js ~/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.21.1.js

yarn --version
```

When running yarn, it should now state the latest (such as 1.22.5 at the time of writing).

Comment: Slight correction. The copy should be in the releases folder that was just created. Right now, it is just copying to the `.yarn` folder

Comment: Thanks. And here I thought I did the steps as I wrote this

Answer (score 0):

```bash
yarn set version <VERSION_NAME>
```

e.g.:   `yarn set version berry` should recreate the `.yarn/releases/` folder with the corresponding version.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, I had a `.yarnrc` file at `~/` which were blocking the execution of yarn at any folder.

Solved by doing:

- Deleted .yarn folder
- Deleted .yarnrc file
- Deleted package.json
- brew reinstall yarn

Done

Answer (score -1):

Turns out manually creating the directory /releases/ and duplicating the cli.js file from /.yarn/lib/ and renaming the duplicate to yarn-1.21.1.js was the solution to this issue. Leaving this here for future reference.

Also, at first I couldn't find the /.yarn/ directory, but installing directly from yarn did the trick, using the following: